# generated by default as identity for varchar data type in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table xx_abc with data existing in the database. 
I want to add a column confi_name in this table which is mandatory column. 
If i add this column like

```
ALTER TABLE xx_abc 
ADD 
( confi_NAME VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL);
```

I am getting an error :

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column
01758. 00000 -  "table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column"
```

So I converted it to

```
ALTER TABLE xx_abc  
ADD 
( confi_name  VARCHAR2(2000) generated by default as identity (START WITH 2, INCREMENT BY 1)
```

But this is also throwing an error because generated by defaut has to be of int data type. I basically want to make config_name with value which is unique for each row. and i cannot change its data type as well. Any work around ?

Comment: Why do you want to store `id` as string? Identity column uses a sequence in background and will always be number.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - It has now have to have name instead of id. I have edited my question and added config_name instead

Answer (score 0):

First add the column as nullable.
Then update that column with a default value in every row.
Then set the column to be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, the table had their values already. If you are going to add another column with "not null" property, make sure that you insert values equal to the number of values(rows) of the previous columns since you had set it to "not null" as its properties. Another way is not to use "not null" first then set the property to "not null" once you have enough values for the column already.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a default value for the existing rows before adding the constraint.

1)Modify the table

```
ALTER TABLE xx_abc 
ADD 
( confi_NAME VARCHAR2(2000));
```

2)Set default values

```
update XX_ABC set confi_NAME = 'DEFAULT';
COMMIT;
```

3)Add the constraint

```
alter table XX_ABC add check (confi_NAME is not null);
```

Comment: Why check constraint? Simply not null is enough.

Comment: @Ricardo arnold-- The problem is not to add a column with not null. But add a sequence as default value for each row that exists

Comment: Hi @divya.trehan573, in that case you can replace step 2 with a small pl/sql block `Begin for i in (select * from XX_ABC) loop update XX_ABC set confi_NAME = my_sequence.nextval where rowid = i.rowid; end loop; commit; end;/`

Answer (score 0):

**Existing table:**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A VARCHAR2(10));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('a');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('b');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('c');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

**Add a new column:**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD (b VARCHAR2(10));

Table altered.
```

**Update the rows:**

```
SQL> UPDATE t SET b = 'newvalue';

3 rows updated.
```

**Add NOT NULL constraint:**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t MODIFY b NOT NULL;

Table altered.

SQL> desc t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------
 A                                                  VARCHAR2(10)
 B                                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)

SQL>
```

Comment: The problem is not to add a column with not null. But add a sequence as default value for each row that exists

Comment: @divya.trehan573 How can you generate an alphabetical sequence? How could `name` ever be a sequence? Can you give an example?